# MVVM and Role Based Security

Tags: c#, mvvm, silverlight-4.0

I have a silverlight application (MVVM) with a view that will be used by multiple roles within the application, the accessibilty of certain ui controls in the view is dependant on the users role. How should this be managed within the view model? Are there any object patterns that I should be considering?

Any ideas/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first idea that comes to mind is to have properties in your ViewModel that correspond to whether or not the current user has the ability to perform certain operations. For example:

```
public bool CanChangeDisplayName {
    get {
        bool result = SomeMechanismToDetermineUsersAbilityToPerformAction();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then you could bind the `IsEnabled` (or `IsReadOnly` or `Visibility`) property on the appropriate controls on your View to this property. Like:

```
<TextBox IsReadOnly="{Binding CanChangeDisplayName}" Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The parts of the view that are role specific are likely in some sort of container (grid, stackpanel, tabitem, etc)  and if that's the case then I would think your solution will hing on the binding you set for the Visibility property.

You would create an application scoped static resource that would facilitate a call to  IsInRole for the current user.  In your binding you'll have to reference a converter (to go from bool to visibility) and it's there that you could pass the name of role you're testing for.

Comment: I would disagree with the bit about changing the Visibility. It might be appropriate in some cases, but not as a general rule. For example, you probably wouldn't want to hide a grid containing invoice line items from the user if they have read-only access - the user wouldn't be able to see them at all!